# Remotely check CPU, memory and disk space IBM Bluemix PHP instance

Tags: php, performance, monitoring, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

Remotely check CPU, memory and disk space IBM Bluemix PHP instance.

I have a php instance running in IBM Bluemix.

Now I want to check the CPU, Memory and Disk Space from an external program by calling a php web page.

For CPU I tried the following function:

```
function get_server_cpu_usage(){
    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    $cores = shell_exec("grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l");
    $load[2] = ($load[2] / $cores) * 100;
    return $load[2];
}
```

For  Memory I use the following function:

```
memory_get_usage(true)
```

For  Disk Space I use the following function:

```
disk_free_space("/")
```

But when I compare these results with the results provided by the IBM Bluemix Console, they are different.

Is there a correct way to externally monitor these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve that information using CF API REST call. You can find the CF APIs documentation here:

- Application summary:
  https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/234/apps/get_app_summary.html
- Detailed application stats: https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/234/apps/get_detailed_stats_for_a_started_app.html

In this specific case you could do a curl call from your php application and parse the JSON response for CPU, Memory and Disk Space information.

> curl "https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/apps/YOURAPP_GUID/summary" -X
>   GET -H "Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidWFhLWlkLTQyNCIsImVtYWlsIjoiZW1haWwtMjkzQHNvbWVkb21haW4uY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlci5hZG1pbiJdLCJhdWQiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlciJdLCJleHAiOjE0NjA1MDY2NjF9.iUpeFnPKDWf3sxvDB0RF2_nSLAkqLZP7iN6Nx0bWE-Q"

You can retrieve the Authorization header with:

```
cf oauth-token
```

after login to IBM Bluemix (cf login)

If you want retrieve the auth-token from your application you should use another REST API before running the first curl get.

> curl -s -X POST -H "Accept-Encoding: application/json" -d
>   "grant_type=password&password=YOURPASSWORD&scope=&username=YOURUSERNAME"
>   -u "cf:" https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token

Comment: I only see the memory and disk space which are installed. Not the memory and disk space which is taken bij de instance when its is running.

Comment: @arjankroon 
the cf call for getting detailed info is
GET /v2/apps/[YOUR APP GUID]/stats

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/234/apps/get_detailed_stats_for_a_started_app.html

Editing the answer

Comment: tx @v.bontempi that was the thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The values you see within the running application should be related to the running virtual process executing the PHP runtime and for this reason the result could be different from what you see from the IBM Bluemix Console in the application dashboard, since the numbers you see don't consider the resources used by the entire runtime.

Moreover you cannot be sure that the values retrieved are referring at the same moment between the two test.

If you need a more powerful tool for performance monitoring you can use the [Monitoring and Analytics](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/monana/index.html#monana_oview) service on IBM Bluemix. Unfortunately the Monitoring & Analytics service does not offer an API to retrieve its collected metrics. We realize that supporting a programmatic interface would be helpful and it's in our backlog to add that capability.

Comment: This is unfortunate.

Is there another way to externally retreive memory usage and CPU usage of a php instance.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
bx cf app <app-name>
```